# How can I select specific model in dbt?

Tags: python, dbt

Based on the dbt [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax), we should be able to select specific models within a certain path.

`dbt run --select myproject/models/abc/mymodel.py`

However this does not work for me, I get this error:

`The selection criterion 'myproject/models/abc/mymodel.py' does not match any nodes`

I am using dbt python models in case that matters.

My dbt project tree sample:

```
├── models
│   ├── other.py
│   ├── other2.py
│   ├── config.yml
│   └── abc
│       ├── config.yml
│       └── mymodel.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems we need to define it like this:

`dbt run --select abc.mymodel`

This is working for me (dbt python model)

Comment: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax "The --select flag is used to specify a subset of nodes to execute." The key word here is "nodes" - the --select parameter expects you to supply the name of a _node_ in the dependency graph, not a file i.e. don't include the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for me

```
dbt run --model your-model-name
```

I can run this from the root directory of all models, and it still finds the correct model.

To ensure to build all its dependent tables use this instead

```
dbt run --model +your-model-name
```

plus-sign in front of the model, builds all the intermediate tables first and then the final table.

Answer (score -2):

The error you are getting is because the `-select` flag in dbt only supports selecting models by their filename, not by their path. So, the correct way to run the mymodel.py model in your project would be to use the following command:

```
dbt run --select mymodel.py
```

The `mymodel.py` model is located in the `models/abc` directory, but dbt doesn't currently support selecting models by their path. This is a limitation of the `--select` flag, and it's something that the dbt team is aware of and working on.

In the meantime, you can work around this limitation by creating a symlink to the `mymodel.py` file in the root of your project directory. Once you've created the symlink, you can then run the `mymodel.py` model using the following command:

```
dbt run --select mymodel.py
```

Here are the steps on how to create a symlink to the mymodel.py file:

- Open a terminal window and navigate to the root directory of your dbt project.
- Run the following command to create a symlink to the mymodel.py file:

  ln -s models/abc/mymodel.py mymodel.py

Once you've created the symlink, you can run the `mymodel.py` model using the `--select` flag.

You can join the dbt(data build tool) community to learn more with other engineers: https://www.getdbt.com/community/

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT